# Getting NaN in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the HTML where date should be exposed:

```
<td><span id="count">{{$b->created_at}}</span></td>
<td><span class="clock"></span></td>
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var inputDate = new Date($('#count').val());
        inputDate.setDate(inputDate.getDate() + 7);
        $(".clock").countdown(inputDate, function(event) {
            $(this).text(event.strftime('%D dienos %Hh %Mmin %Ssek'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

But at the end of the day I'm getting this: `NaN dienos NaNh NaNmin NaNse`

Comment: `<span>`s don't have a [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) (that method is only relevant to form elements, e.g. `<input>`). They can however have [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: I strongly recommend using parseInt() every single time when interacting with DOM values to avoid pain

Comment: Even then, you should not rely on `new Date()` parsing it correctly. Instead you should break down the string and provide `new Date()` with the result.

Comment: @VladimirRamik Always? Sometimes you might expect a string too, or a decimal ...

Comment: Sorry - I meant in your case with number addition in setDate. Yes, parseFloat, toString() have their place as needed especially if you're using triple equals.